# Forms in Angular 2 RC4

Tags: angular

I am experimenting with forms in Angular 2 RC4.
It's all working fine but when I start the app the browser console gives me this message:

```
*It looks like you're using the old forms module. This will be opt-in in the next RC, and will eventually be removed in favor of the new forms module.
```

The relevant part of my component looks like this:

```
import {
    FORM_DIRECTIVES,
    REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES,
    FormBuilder,
    FormGroup
} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

@Component
({
    selector: "hh-topbar",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "topBar.component.html",
    directives: [HHPagerComponent, FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class HHTopBarComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit
{
    ...
    private filterForm: FormGroup;
    private title$: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder)
    {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): any
    {
        this.filterForm = this.formBuilder.group
        ({
            "title": [this.info.filters.searchFileName]
        });

        this.title$ = this.filterForm.controls["title"].valueChanges;
        this.title$.subscribe(val =>
        {
            this.info.filters.searchFileName = val;
            this.filterChanged.emit(this.info.filters);
        });
    }
}
```

And the relevant part of my template looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="filterForm">
    <div>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input [formControl]="filterForm.controls['title']" id="title" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Does anybody here know what is the new forms module the warning is talking about and which directives will change and to what?

Comment: whats the use of `REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES` here ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to explicitly disable the deprecated form support when bootstrapping your application:

```
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  disableDeprecatedForms()
  provideForms()
]);
```

Whereas `FormBuilder` isn't deprecated, you can use directly the `FormGroup` class instead:

```
this.filterForm = new FormGroup({
  title: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});
```

Comment: This did the trick and thanks for your tip about using the FormGroup class directly. Very helpful. As far as you know, will the form directives I am using make into the actual first release?

Comment: whats the use of `REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES` here @ThierryTemplier ?

Comment: @PardeepJain - I believe that REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES includes the directives for model-driven forms (e.g. formControlName), whereas FORM_DIRECTIVES includes the directives form template-driven forms (e.g. ngModel).

Comment: Thanks @carlo for info