# angular 2 rc.5: It looks like you're using the old forms module

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I upgraded to rc5 of angular 2 and all of a sudden I am getting this notice again:

> It looks like you're using the old forms module

I moved to the new Forms API with rc4 and I am definetly not importing the "DeprecatedFormsModule"

How come that angular logs this warning, even though I am most certainly not using any old forms?

**EDIT:**
Actually I can trigger this warning just by adding `<form></form>` to the html of a component. If I remove that form-tag, the warning disappears, too.

**EDIT2:**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './app/';


if (environment.enableAngularProductionMode) {
    enableProdMode();
}

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: We're going to need to see your code to double check that you didn't miss something somewhere.

Comment: it's a 50+ files project...

Comment: Which means there's a much larger chance that you missed something small somewhere. I guess since it's infeasible to put the files up, some info about the bootstrapper might be helpful?

Comment: I added the main.ts

Answer (score 4):

**Solved it:**

I searched the whole project for "FORM_DIRECTIVES" and removed them from every component in the project (also "REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES")

Additionally I imported the "ReactiveFormsModule" in app.module.ts

Everything you need is here: http://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

Answer (score 1):

Try to add on your bootstraper `disableDeprecatedForms()` like below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [..,
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  ...]);
```

To use `disableDeprecatedForms` you need to import it from `'@angular/forms'`

```
import {disableDeprecatedForms} from '@angular/forms';
```

**Credit**: [Forms in Angular 2 RC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197255/forms-in-angular-2-rc4)

Comment: I am using "platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);" to bootstrap

Comment: @TobiasGassmann Could you please provide us some more code about your bootstraper?

Answer (score 0):

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule,[ disableDeprecatedForms(),provideForms()]);